# Assembly Language x86 Irvine32

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, irvine32

I'm fairly new to Assembly Language and I'm trying to figure out this program. Just want to know if I'm on point with the program. How do I correct this program?

> Write a loop that computes the sum of all the elements in the array of bytes. Print the result. Some hints: Load the size of the array into an appropriate register. Load the offset of the current element of the array and change it accordingly on every iteration of the loop.

Here's what I have so far:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
  val1 BYTE 1,2,3
  counter = 0
.code

main PROC

  mov ax, 0

  mov ax, (LENGTHOF val1)
  mov ax, OFFSET Counter
  movzx ecx,ax
L1:
  add eax, val1[ecx]
  inc eax

loop L1

  Call WriteDec

exit
 END PROC
   end main
```

Comment: _"How do I correct this program?"_ In what way does it not work as intended?

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors in your code: In the following sequence you repeatedly set ax which is pretty useless:

```
mov ax, 0                          ; you set ax to 0
mov ax, (LENGTHOF val1)            ; you set ax to 3
mov ax, OFFSET Counter             ; you set ax to an address (and try to use a 16-bit register for a 32-bit address
```

Then you add this offset to another offset in

```
movzx ecx,ax
L1:
  add eax, val1[ecx]               ; add offset(val1)[offset(Counter)] to offset(Counter)
```

With certainty, this will give you a memory error, because the address may be anywhere. Then you increase this offset with

```
inc eax                            ; you probably confused this with a counter/index register
```

And after that you use this offset in ECX, which you put in there by `movzx ecx, ax` as an index in ECX in the `LOOP` instruction

```
loop L1                            ; decrements ECX and loops if ECX != 0
```

---

After fixing all of these errors, the code could look like this:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc    
.data
  val1 BYTE 1,2,3
  counter = 0
.code
main:    
  xor eax, eax                     ; 32-bit register for the sum
  xor edx, edx                     ; 32-bit register for the counter/index
  mov ecx, LENGTHOF val1           ; number of entries in fixed size array in ECX as maximum limit
L1:
  movsx ebx, byte ptr val1[edx]    ; extend BYTE at offset val1 + EDX to 32-bit 
  add eax, ebx                     ; add extended BYTE value to accumulator
  inc edx                          ; increase index in EDX
loop L1                            ; decreases ECX and jumps if not zero

  Call WriteDec                    ; I assume this prints EAX
  exit
end main
```

Comment: **add eax, val1[edx]      ; offset of val1 + EDX** Isn't this an invalid instruction operand? I feel like this is why I have the problem.

Comment: Yes. You're right, I forgot that the array is of BYTE size. I modified the code to reflect that. In this case `MOVSX` moves 8-bit from memory to a 32-bit register (signed).

Comment: You could avoid clobbering a register that's usually callee-saved (`ebx`) if you loop with `inc edx / cmp edx, LENGTHOF val1 / jle`.  That frees up ecx as a scratch for movsx.  Or your could access the array in reverse order, so you can still use a dec-and-branch loop.  (Although then you'd use `val1 - 1 [edx]`, because you elements 0..len-1, not 1..len).  Or you could even loop fowards with a counter starting at `-LENGTHOF val1`, counting up towards zero.  Load from `val1 + LENGTHOF val1 [edx]` or something.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Of course your suggested improvements would be close to perfection, but I refrained from implementing them, because this was a beginner question. Hence, I tried to stay as close as possible to the original implementation and just tried to realize the minimum of needed fixes/interventions to get the code 'running'. BTW I always appreciate your input.

Comment: I started out that comment to say you should maybe save/restore `ebx`, and got carried away :P  But I guess `exit` means `main` doesn't return?

Comment: I though about saving `EBX`, but because it would be destroyed anyway by `exit` at the end of the program, I chose to disregard its impact. :-)